# how to calculate the number of unique words just in a part of a file

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have a file in Persian (a Persian sentence, a "tab", then a Persian word, again a "tab" and then an English word). I have to calculate the number of unique words just in Persian sentences and not the Persian and English words after the tabs. Here's the code:

```
from hazm import*

file = "F.txt"
def WordsProbs (file):
    words = set()
    with open (file, encoding = "utf-8") as f1:
        normalizer = Normalizer()
        for line in f1:
            tmp = line.strip().split("\t")
            words.update(set(normalizer.normalize(tmp[0].split())))
    print(len(words), "unique words")
    print (words)
```

To access just the sentences I have to split each line by "\t". And to access each word of the sentence I have to split tmp[0]. The problem is, when I run the code the error below occurs. It's because of the split after tmp[0]. But if I omit this split after tmp[0], it just counts the letters not unique words. How can I fix it? (Is there another way to write this code to calculate unique words?).

The error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yasini\Desktop\16.py", line 15, in 
    WordsProbs (file)
  File "C:\Users\yasini\Desktop\16.py", line 10, in WordsProbs
    words.update(set(normalizer.normalize(tmp[0].split())))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\hazm\Normalizer.py", line 46, in normalize
    text = self.character_refinement(text)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\hazm\Normalizer.py", line 65, in character_refinement
    text = text.translate(self.translations)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translate'

sample file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r88hglemg7aot0w/F.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself.

```
from hazm import*

file = "F.txt"
def WordsProbs (file):
    words = []
    mergelist = []
    with open (file, encoding = "utf-8") as f1:
        normalizer = Normalizer()
        for line in f1:
            line = normalizer.normalize(line)
            tmp = line.strip().split("\t")
            words = tmp[0].split()
            #print(len(words), "unique words")
            #print (words)
            for i in words:
                mergelist.append(i)
                uniq = set(mergelist)
                uniqueWords = len(uniq)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that hazm.Normalizer.normalize takes a space separated string as an argument NOT a list. You can see an example [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hazm/0.5.2) under the "Usage" heading.

Remove the `.split()` from the argument to your normalize function so that

```
words.update(set(normalizer.normalize(tmp[0].split())))
```

becomes

```
words.update(set(normalizer.normalize(tmp[0])))
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried it before. If I omit that, it counts the letters not words.